# Why does NotifyIcon not set SynchronizationContext?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, synchronizationcontext

Consider this WinForms program:

```
Module Main
    Dim notifyicon As New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
    'Dim dummycontrol As New System.Windows.Forms.Control

    Public Sub Main()
        If (System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current Is Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Something")
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

NotifyIcon is a WinForm control, and requires a message loop, so why will declaring `dummycontrol` (or any WinForms control) set a SynchronizationContext, but the NotifyIcon does not?

Comment: `NotifyIcon` [doesn't inherit](http://imgur.com/SfpxNAF) from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` - does that change the premise of your question?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you; a telling observation for sure, and explains why it doesn't exhibit the same behavior as other controls, but I'm still curious why a context wouldn't be set despite that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you can discover from the Reference Source, the synchronization provider is installed by the [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,06282f9a00b38e67,references) method.  Look at the references to see when it is called:

- Application.Run()
- The Control class constructor
- The helper method that dispatches Begin/Invoke() calls (won't happen).

NotifyIcon is derived from Component, not Control, so never hits one of those 3 bullets.  It is a thin wrapper around the [Shell_NotifyIcon()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function.  I suppose you can call it bug that its constructor doesn't call InstallIfNeeded() but that's a bit of a stretch, you always must call Application.Run() to make it functional so you'll always hit the 1st bullet.  Just beware initialization order.