# Windows UI Automation doesn't recognize button controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, ui-automation

I'm having problems trying to identify via *Windows UI Automation* the button controls that are inside the *Notification Area* window (classname: **ToolbarWindow32**):

[image]

I verified via the *Windows UI Automation* tools deployed in the *Windows SDK* that those "icons" are controls of type `ControlType.Button`, however when I try to run the code below I get a null-reference exception because the search condition I use doesn't get any control.

I'm doing something wrong, or maybe I found some kind of limitation in *Windows UI Automation* ?

This is the code, I mixed it with WinAPI calls just to facilitate the task for the helper users who maybe preffers to use that methodology.

```
Dim tskBarClassName As String = "Shell_TrayWnd"
Dim tskBarHwnd As IntPtr = NativeMethods.FindWindow(tskBarClassName, Nothing)

Dim systrayBarClassName As String = "TrayNotifyWnd"
Dim systrayBarHwnd As IntPtr = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(tskBarHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, systrayBarClassName, Nothing)

Dim ntfyBarClassName As String = "ToolbarWindow32"
Dim ntfyBarHwnd As IntPtr = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(systrayBarHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, ntfyBarClassName, Nothing)

Dim window As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(ntfyBarHwnd)
Dim condition As New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button)
Dim button As AutomationElement = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condition)

MsgBox(button.Current.Name) ' Here throws the null-reference exception.
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Also, I don't know how the Windows UI Automation tools work, but have you also checked with Spy++?

Comment: @Visual Vincent Hi, thanks for comment. I'm using Windows 10 x64, yes I checked first the values with WinSpy++ too but it is a deprecated tool (said by Microsoft, not me), seems it can't spy through the childs of the **ToolbarWindow32** window, then I used instead **Visual UI Automation Verify** tool (from Windows SDK) to verify it all before asking here, however I'm not an expert of control-trees and window hierarchy so maybe I could did something wrong when cheking. The Windows UI automation Id of the **ToolbarWindow32** window is **1504** in my Windows 10.

Comment: I tried to call **EnumChildWindows** function on the **ToolbarWindow32** window, which stores the notify icons (are button controls), however **EnumChildWindows** doesn't retrieve any child window handle inside the **ToolbarWindow32** window, I only can idenify those notifyicon-buttons using the **Visual UI Automation** tool from Windows SDK... so strange.

Comment: Strange... Maybe the icons aren't actually owned by the task bar, but just drawn on the screen or something? (Just doing some speculations here) -- And for the record, WinSpy++ and Spy++ is not the exact same thing. WinSpy++ is made by a third-party developer and Spy++ is made by Microsoft. Though I cannot find anything saying it would be deprecated. It's still shipped with the latest Visual Studio.

Comment: It's no help really, but I can confirm (via Winspector) that none of "Shell_TrayWnd > TrayNotifyWnd > ToolbarWindow32", "Shell_TrayWnd > TrayNotifyWnd > SysPager > ToolbarWindow32" nor "NotifyIconOverflowWindow" possess children on my system. Additionally, none of my system tray icons appear as "windows" in Winspector. Possibly related: It was pointed out to me in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965262/why-does-notifyicon-not-set-synchronizationcontext) that despite having a message loop, NotifyIcon does not behave like a standard control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I verified via the Windows UI Automation tools deployed in the Windows SDK that those "icons" are controls of type ControlType.Button

You are correct ***somewhat***. Technically they are *not in ToolbarWindow32, rather Shell_TrayWnd*. I inspected the area and found out, those buttons are actually in a `ToolBar`, so you need to look for the `ControlType.ToolBar`. Next you need to `FindAll` which will return all AutomationElements that would satisfy the `PropertyCondition`...

**Note: the first loop is to get the User Promoted Notification Area. The next loop for fun is getting the Running Application buttons... (CODE IS WORKING ON WIN7, WIN8 and WIN10)**

Here in my example below, I go after the `Shell_TrayWnd` which will get us what we would need. Then I go through and find what `ToolBar` we are after, then loop through and `FindAll` ControlTypes of `Button`...

```
Dim arrText As New List(Of String)
        Dim tskBarClassName As String = "Shell_TrayWnd"
        Dim tskBarHwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(tskBarClassName, Nothing)
        Dim window As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(tskBarHwnd)
        Dim condition As New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ToolBar)
        Dim elementCollection As AutomationElementCollection = window.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condition)

        'for fun get all we can...
        For Each aE As AutomationElement In elementCollection
            If aE.Current.Name.Equals("User Promoted Notification Area") Then
                For Each ui As AutomationElement In aE.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button))
                    arrText.Add("Notification Area - " & Replace(ui.Current.HelpText, Chr(10), " "c)) 'removed line break as when shown it would show some on a new line in messagebox
                Next
            ElseIf aE.Current.Name.Equals("Running applications") Then
                For Each ui As AutomationElement In aE.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button))
                    arrText.Add("Toolbar Area - " & Replace(ui.Current.Name, Chr(10), " "c)) 'removed line break as when shown it would show some on a new line in messagebox
                Next
            End If

        Next

If arrText.Count > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrText.ToArray))
        End If
```

If you have any questions, please let me know. Image below (some things I commented out for secure reasons)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, just I would like to note that the provided solution will not work on a non-English Windows because the hardcoded English-localized names in the code, then maybe a better solution could be to compare the classnames instead (**ToolbarWindow32**, **MSTaskListWClass**), which at least works for me.